# Exibir Imagem List View

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

Tenho uma tela, que através de um List View, exibo uma foto por registro listado.

```
 <td class="col-md-1 text-center" style="vertical-align: middle">
    <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "~/ControlePatio/Veiculo/ExibirFotos.aspx?CodigoFoto=" + Eval("Foto") %>' Width="130" Height="90" />
 </td>
```

As fotos estão salvas no banco dedados e o problema é que, para cada registro encontrado, é feito um select na página "ExibirFotos", que retorna um array de bytes. Este fator influencia na performance do sistema quando é exibido muitos registros nessa tela.

Eu gostaria de não ter que fazer esse outro select para preencher o componente Image.